# dir command - search for file names with partial string and file extension

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

I have a hard drive containing really unorganized folders of movie files. Now I want to use the dir cmd command to search for the following:
- a filename, containing both the strings 'holiday' and '2017', in no particular order, and the file extension must match any of the following: .mov .mp4 .avi

Note that the strings 'holiday' and '2017' are not necessarily next to each other, there can be other words in between.

How to achieve this? I played around with `dir /s` combined with `findstr` but no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How to achieve this? I played around with `dir /s` combined with findstr but no success

You need to use `findstr` twice, together with `dir /b /s`, something like the following (not tested):

```
dir /b /s *.mov *.mp4 *.avi | findstr /i "holiday" | findstr "2017"
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.